# Toshiba Tecra A8 without audio with Ubuntu 14.04 Bug alsa

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa

Sound used to work but now it doesn't.

```
uname -a
Linux PCIFP26 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP 
Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 0: ALC262 Analog [ALC262 Analog]
  Subdispositivos: 0/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0
tarjeta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 6: Si3054 Modem [Si3054 Modem]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0

head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*
==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==
Codec: Realtek ALC262

==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#1 <==
Codec: LSI Si3054
```

**alsa-base.conf file**

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS
 && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

Any ideas, of what it can be.

Comment: With pavucontrol ubuntu, I can see that sound is detected and when a sound is on, you can see the line waving

Comment: If you dual boot with Windows 8, [see this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/464444/258567). If headphones work, and the speaker doesn't work or works intermittently, please click "Does this bug affect you?" in the upper left of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020).

Answer (score 1):

[SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

**Step 9**

If you are using a dual boot system (even with Windows and Ubuntu installed on separate partitions), then make sure to set the sound volume in Windows to a high level before booting into Ubuntu. Also make sure to use the special function keys in Windows to make sure the loudspeakers are physically switched ON and working properly in Windows before installing and testing Ubuntu. This step is necessary with certain Toshiba Tecra laptops.